# No console logs in terminal with Ionic run

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I am trying to `ionic cordova run ios -lcs` or just `-cs` on an iphone 5s connected via usb to a mac (OSX 10.11.6).

The app runs on the iPhone but I don't see any JavaScript logs in the terminal. And I don't see the device listed in the Development menu in Safari.

ionic info

```
[ERROR] Error with
    /Users/ludux/Documents/PROJETS/BOINE/dev/ne/www/lib/ionic/version.json
    file: FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.4.0
Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1 
Gulp CLI         : not installed globally
Ionic CLI        : 3.4.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova : 1.4.0
@ionic/cli-plugin-gulp    : 1.0.1
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic1  : 2.0.0
Cordova Platforms         : ios 4.3.1
Ionic Framework           : unknown
```

System:

```
Node       : v7.2.0
OS         : OS X El Capitan
Xcode      : Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002 
ios-deploy : 1.9.0 
ios-sim    : 5.0.8 
npm        : 3.10.9
```

End of compilation log in terminal:

```
------ Debug phase ------
Starting debug of iPhone 5s (Global/CDMA) 'iPhone de Lou' (5910f2d7cc2f113756d5de4b942029559ea0cd38) connected through USB...
[  0%] Looking up developer disk image
[ 95%] Developer disk image mounted successfully
[100%] Connecting to remote debug server
-------------------------
(lldb) command source -s 0 '/tmp/E6C7DA82-1774-45A2-B4B2-0CD3988AE4BD/fruitstrap-lldb-prep-cmds-5910f2d7cc2f113756d5de4b942029559ea0cd38'
Executing commands in '/tmp/E6C7DA82-1774-45A2-B4B2-0CD3988AE4BD/fruitstrap-lldb-prep-cmds-5910f2d7cc2f113756d5de4b942029559ea0cd38'.
(lldb)     platform select remote-ios --sysroot '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/10.2 (14C89)/Symbols'
  Platform: remote-ios
 Connected: no
  SDK Path: "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/10.2 (14C89)/Symbols"
(lldb)     target create "/Users/ludovicroux/Documents/PROJETS/BOARDLINE/dev/boardline/platforms/ios/build/device/BoardLine.app"
Current executable set to '/Users/ludovicroux/Documents/PROJETS/BOARDLINE/dev/boardline/platforms/ios/build/device/BoardLine.app' (arm64).
(lldb)     script fruitstrap_device_app="/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/13EA02BB-85A1-4818-ACDB-161AC1DDE62E/BoardLine.app"
(lldb)     script fruitstrap_connect_url="connect://127.0.0.1:59590"
(lldb)     command script import "/tmp/E6C7DA82-1774-45A2-B4B2-0CD3988AE4BD/fruitstrap_5910f2d7cc2f113756d5de4b942029559ea0cd38.py"
(lldb)     command script add -f fruitstrap_5910f2d7cc2f113756d5de4b942029559ea0cd38.connect_command connect
(lldb)     command script add -s asynchronous -f fruitstrap_5910f2d7cc2f113756d5de4b942029559ea0cd38.run_command run
(lldb)     command script add -s asynchronous -f fruitstrap_5910f2d7cc2f113756d5de4b942029559ea0cd38.autoexit_command autoexit
(lldb)     command script add -s asynchronous -f fruitstrap_5910f2d7cc2f113756d5de4b942029559ea0cd38.safequit_command safequit
(lldb)     connect
(lldb)     run
success
(lldb)     safequit
Process 308 detached
(lldb)
```

Comment: Does your app build and launch successfully on device? No compilation errors?

Comment: yes it seems to build nicely, I don't see compilation errors. I am adding the end of the terminal log in the question.

Comment: Do you have the latest version `1.3.7` of `ionic-app-scripts`?

Comment: I don't know, how to get the version ? There's seems to be warning and unmet dependies in my npm distribution...